# How to get google app engine logs in C#?

Tags: c#, google-app-engine

I am trying to retrieve app engine logs the only result I get is "# next_offset=None", below is my code:

```
    internal string GetLogs()
    {

        string result = _connection.Get("/api/request_logs", GetPostParameters(null));
        return result;
    }
    private Dictionary<string, string> GetPostParameters(Dictionary<string, string> customParameters)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() { 
                                                                                    { "app_id", _settings.AppId }, 
                                                                                    { "version", _settings.Version.ToString() } 
                                                                                 };
        if (customParameters != null)
        {
            foreach (string key in customParameters.Keys)
            {
                if (parameters.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    parameters[key] = customParameters[key];
                }
                else
                {
                    parameters.Add(key, customParameters[key]);
                }
            }
        }

        return parameters;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This method requires version parameter to be version.1